# How add icon to nodes in vis.js

Tags: javascript, networking, vis.js

I created network in vis.js, but I need add icon to node, for example "plus", and then add handler to this icon.
How I can do this?

Comment: post your code also??

Answer (score 0):

You should set the node shape to icon, then use `icon` option.

See the [official documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html) for more information.

Comment: No,no. I need have node and icon, not node like icon